# Why doesn't the Navigation Drawer respond to a swipe?

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer

There were problems when building the old project because of Gradle, decided to create a new project, moved the main files, re-installed all the packages and Navigation Drawer stopped work, with no warnings and errors, does not respond to gestures, while the old project is working fine. I tried reinstalling `react-native-gesture-handler` and all packages related to Navigation, but it didn't help. By the way, if I use `navigation.openDrawer();`, the side menu opens itself, but still does not respond to gestures (swipe). Also followed this point in the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project).
What are the options for solving this problem?

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import AccountScreen from "../containers/AccountScreen";
import ShopListScreen from "../containers/ShopListScreen";
import OrdersScreen from "../containers/OrdersScreen";
import AddressScreen from "../containers/AddressScreen";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigation = () => (
  <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={ShopListScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Orders" component={OrdersScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Address" component={AddressScreen} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
);

export default DrawerNavigation;
```

- react-navigation/drawer@5.12.3
- react-navigation/native@5.9.2
- react-native-gesture-handler@1.10.0
- react-native@0.63.4
- react@16.13.1
- Android 9